# Autowire not working with controller Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Whenever I am trying to autowire a custom repository implementing JPA Repository within my controller class it is unable to do so and throwing a no bean def found error whereas if I am doing the same with any Service Class its working fine. Can anyone please explain to me why is it so?

```````````````````````````
Spring Boot 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2020-02-15 13:01:50.169 ERROR 16304 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Field customerRepo in Controllers.MainController required a bean of type 'Repository.CustomerRepo' that could not be found.

    The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


    Action:

    Consider defining a bean of type 'Repository.CustomerRepo' in your configuration.

    ```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "Controllers")
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
    ``````````````````
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class MainController {

        @Autowired
        private CustomerRepo customerRepo;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String homePage() {
            Customer testCustomer = new Customer();
            testCustomer.setFirstName("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setLastName("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setMiddleName("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setAddressLine("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setCountry("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setPincode(713201);
            testCustomer.setState("csdcsdccs");
            testCustomer.setDateOfBirth(new Date(2019, 5, 13));

            customerRepo.save(testCustomer);

            return "inserted";
        }
    }

    `````````````
    @Repository
    public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    }
    ``````````````````````````
```````````````````````````

Comment: Before your question is down voted and closed , update the question with relevant code. Also , make sure your repository is ComponentScan-ned.

Comment: Is the `CustomerRepo` type in the `Controllers` package or a sub-package thereof? No, it's in the `Repository` package, so why would you expect it to be found, when you told Spring to only scan the `Controllers` package?

Comment: Please do read through section [Structuring Your Code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code) from reference documentation as well.

Comment: Does repository class is in the same package as controllers if so just add repository package to @ComponentScan

Answer (score 0):

Spring application is unable to scan the repository. Could you please check if the repository is defined defined under the base package otherwise add Repository repository package also in @ComponentScan there.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Controllers","Repository"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"Controllers","Repository"})` would be more concise.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but I have tried both the ways you have defined but in either case the result is same. ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field customerRepo in Controllers.MainController required a bean of type 'Repository.CustomerRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'Repository.CustomerRepo' in your configuration.

Comment: Can you show complete code for Repo, along with package and import statements

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `@Component` or `@Repository` annotations on you Repo?